# Tailwind CSS align vertical row in centre

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have a simple text and image in a row. But the image is not showing in centre to text.

#### My code

```
<div class="w-28 flex justify-center items-center align-middle">
    <div>
        asd
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="assets/Vector 35.png" class="w-4 align-middle">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Preview

[image]

Comment: Did you mean something like that? https://play.tailwindcss.com/4dSjNbSJnF

Answer (score 0):

#### Use  `items-baseline`

---

It is actually `centre` if you watch carefully.

But for your situation change `items-center` to `items-baseline` to get the desired behavior

```
<div class="relative flex w-28 items-baseline justify-center">
  <div class="text-4xl">asd</div>
  <div>
    <img src="assets/Vector 35.png" class="w-6" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output using `items-center`

[image]

#### Output using `items-baseline`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just add "absolute" to your text

```
<div class="w-28 flex justify-center items-center align-middle">
    <div class="absolute">
        asd
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="assets/Vector 35.png" class="w-4 align-middle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added absolute but then the image overlaps with text

Comment: My bad, think i misunderstood your question. If the things that you want is like what @ChenBr send then make your image smaller and add some vertical margin will do the job